# javascript to calculate the top padding of different divs and scroll exactly at the top of the respective divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to create anchors to scroll down to the elements of the same page. but when I do, the title of the div block is hidden. The top part of the block is hidden and it stops in the middle of the div block.

This code just scrolls down the div but it would be nice if we could include something to land exactly at the top of the div

This is my js code

```
function init_anchors(target, time) {
  var start = new Date().getTime(),

    timer = setInterval(function() {
      var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
      document.body['scrollTop'] = (step * target.offsetTop);
      if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 25);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show your markup aswell.

Comment: I would recommend using a prebuilt library, perhaps http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/